# When did Intel undergo the SEX change?

Tags: assembly, intel

I am reading the book [*"The 8086 / 8088 Primer Second Edition"* by Stephen P Morse](https://www.stevemorse.org/8086/index.html). In it on page 54, it says

> The 8086 provides instructions to facilitate the task of sign extension. These instructions were initially named `SEX` (*s*ign *ex*tend) but were later renamed to [...] `CBW` (*c*onvert *b*yte to *w*ord), and `CWD` (*c*onvert *w*ord to *d*ouble word).

What Intel chip provided the primitive `SEX` (as documented) and what was the last chip produced before Intel underwent the `SEX` change documenting the new `SEX`-equivalent differently.

Comment: The naming of opcodes is completely transparent to the chip itself.  The chip uses numbers to identify specific operations, and the name we assign to any particular number in a document (or in a program like an assembler) is somewhat arbitrary.  Changing the name of an opcode does not actually require any change to the chip itself, only to the documentation and tools people who work with the chip will use.

Comment: @KenGober good point, I tried to reflect that better.

Comment: Clickbait title much?

Answer (score 12):

> What Intel chip provided the primitive `SEX` and what was the last chip produced before Intel underwent the `SEX` change?

None, as that's a function which is only needed if a CPU operates on words longer than 8 bit - something no previous 8 bit (intel) CPU did.

It was a new instruction created for the 8086, so a 8 bit value could be sign extended to 16 bit for further 16 bit operations. Mr. Morse, who did the whole instruction level design for the 8086, named it `SEX` in his design, but got overruled later on.

---

So if you excuse extending the pun, it was never a girl, the proud father just hoped for one :)

---

As a side note, as [Martin Rosenau](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/8712/martin-rosenau) reminded me [in his comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/when-did-intel-undergo-the-sex-change/7964?noredirect=1#comment23100_7963), the [Motorola 6809](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6809), released the same year as the 8086, did call their sign extension operation `SEX`, which extended an 8 bit value in accumulator `B` into the 16 bit accumulator `D` (where `B` is the lower half anyway).

Comment: Some sort  of useful link here http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/SEX.html

Comment: On the 6809 CPU the `SEX` instruction (named exactly like this) extends the 8-bit value in `B` register into a 16-bit value in `A:B` register pair. `cwd` on the 8086 also operates with a register pair as destination. An instruction doing the same (sign-extending the `L` register into `H:L` pair) would have been thinkable on the 8080, too. So the `SEX` or `CBW` instruction does not necessarily require a 16-bit CPU.

Comment: @MartinRosenau you're perfectly right, that's why it isn't about '8 bit CPU' but 8bit vs. 16 bit **operation**

Answer (score 1):

The first CMOS microprocessor, the CDP1802, has a 4-bit "X" register which is used to select one of 16 registers for use with many opcodes including those for arithmetic and bitwise operations.  That particular chip uses 16 opcodes 0xE0 through 0xEF, called "SEX 0" through "SEX 15", to set X to one of 16 values.  I'm unaware of any Intel chips making use of that mnemonic, however.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the 1802 was designed by Intel. - Serious, while the information provided is nice and great to know, it is in no way related to the question. It's neither the same instruction, not (as requested) by an Intel CPU. Bottom line - itshould be a comment (and would get my upvote as such).

Comment: "I'm unaware of any Intel chips making use of that mnemonic" <-- answers the question

Comment: @fadden: Perhaps, I thought expanding the question to "did any chips use the mnemonic" would be helpful for anyone who might wonder if the existence of such instructions was just a rumor.

Comment: @Raffzahn comments are not meant to be kept so could be deleted at anytime so this would not be of any use as a comment

Comment: @Mark Ofc they are - at least that's the way they are ment and handled on RC.  Coments are supposed to hold additional information which dies not qualify as an answer. Comments are not for any lengthy discussion and such will be (usually) deleted. Last but not least, above isn't answering the question - after all, adding an "I don't know" to an otherwise unrelated writeup doesn't make it one.

Comment: @Raffzahn Comments are for requesting additional information and suggesting improvements. People add extra information in them, and I don't like to delete ones that do, but it's not what they're for and there are systems that can delete them. This qualifies as an answer to the question, since it provides one as fadden has correctly stated: the answer is "Intel chips, to my knowledge, didn't use `SEX`."

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Serious? You consinder that 8 word sentence a valid answer? Does it mean we no longer are supposed to write a meaningful answer at all, just 'yeah' or 'nay', and hide that beneth a non related rant? Gee, not exatly the system I would go and look for a serious answer. In all kindness, you should reconsidere your position for good.

Comment: The question clearly asks about Intel.  The 1802 was designed by RCA.  This answer is irrelevant.  It is like claiming that MULS (Motorola) was renamed IDIV (Intel).

Comment: @DrSheldon: The site is intended not only to collect answers to immediate questions, but also to serve as a searchable collection of answers for future people with questions.  Whether or not the original poster is interested in non-Intel processors' SEX instructions, it would seem likely that other people who find the question would be.

Comment: Ahh, I remember fondly my COMX-35 and its frankly bizarre SCRT call and return instructions :-)

Comment: Down voted, since the question clearly states another CPU

Comment: @Raffzahn It's valid; I never said it was _good_. The policy is never to delete answers that answer the question, even if they're bad or wrong. That's what downvotes are for. Your answer is higher on the default display order, so it isn't much of a problem anyway.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 What you basicly telling here is that I wasted a year of my lifetime (trying) to write sensible answer, when I could have posted quick half way thru and untrelated stuff as well as a simple 'got no idea' under each question? That careing for the quality of that site is not rely of interest? Thank you for clearly pointing that out.

Comment: @Raffzahn No... I appreciate the work you've been doing, and the quality of the site is important. It's just that deleting an answer that I think is "poor" or "low quality" could lead to me deleting answers that I don't agree with, or that "rival" my own, etc. There isn't a hard boundary, so the policy is "if it makes an attempt, don't delete it". Feel free to downvote it if you think it's a poor answer, but if it's an answer it should be kept.

Comment: @Raffzahn: If there is an answer which  answers a direct question, but other people might benefit from additional information, I don't see any particular reason to duplicate the information in the other answer, since anyone who wants that information will have seen it in the other answer.  If you don't think people who are interested in "SEX" opcode questions in general would be particularly likely visit this question, that's possible.  On the other hand,I don't think there are going to be so many answers posted to this question as to cause an excessive amount of clutter.